# Fragment not resumed with its activity after using intent sharing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, intentfilter

**Context**:
I have an app using `Activities` and `Fragments`.
I pause it to access to another one like Google Translate. From the GTranslate, I use the share `Intent` process to send a text data to my app with `intent-filter` `ACTION_SEND`.
Even if the first app was in background its current `activity` is re-created.

The **problem** is that the `fragment` associated to the `activity` mentioned is not re-created too and more annoying not resumed (the `onResume` method of the fragment is never called).

**Question**:
Why in using `intent` through apps, `fragments` don't follow their parent activity's lifecycle and are not at least resumed ?
Is there a way to get around this issue ?

*Or am I totally wrong ?*

Answer (score 0):

Use a Fragment Activity instead of Activity.

From [FragmentActiviy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResume%28%29):

> Dispatch onResume() to fragments. Note that for better inter-operation
>   with older versions of the platform, at the point of this call the
>   fragments attached to the activity are not resumed. This means that in
>   some cases the previous state may still be saved, not allowing
>   fragment transactions that modify the state. To correctly interact
>   with fragments in their proper state, you should instead override
>   {@link #onResumeFragments().

So, the right place to manipulate your fragments in your FragmentActivity is overriding the onResumeFragments method like this:

```
protected void onResumeFragments(){    
super.onResumeFragments();

        // YOUR STUFF IS HERE
}
```

Comment: Even in manipulating fragments in `onResumeFragments`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Some code snippets of what you are doing would be helpful. After re-reading your post, it sounds like you are opening another instance of your app with the Google Translate share intent, vice using something like onActivityResult(), bundle, etc. to receive the data from GTranslate, hence your original app doesn't receive the data and also the original fragment gets stopped.